# How do you put a layout view within a layout view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms

In WebForms you can put a master page inside another master page.
How do you do the same in MVC with Razor?

Can you put a layout view within a layout view?

Or should I be using some other technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  This article explains it very clearly. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/164/Nested-Layout-Pages-with-Razor